# Solr facet doesn't segment text

Tags: json, database, solr

I am a beginner of Solr. I push the books.json into Solr, which looks like

```
{
"id" : "978-0641723445",
"cat" : ["book","hardcover"],
"name" : "The Lightning Thief",
"author" : "Rick Riordan",
"series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians",
"sequence_i" : 1,
"genre_s" : "fantasy",
"inStock" : true,
"price" : 12.50,
"pages_i" : 384
}
```

then I change the schema of "name" to 
`<field name="name" type="text_general"/>` with everything else unchanged. The Analysis in Solr gives correct segmentation. However, when I run the query `http://localhost:8983/solr/testCore/select?facet.field=name&facet=on&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json`

the output is not segmented:

```
"facet_counts":{
"facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{
  "name":[
    "Lucene in Action, Second Edition",1,
    "Sophie's World : The Greek Philosophers",1,
    "The Lightning Thief",1,
    "The Sea of Monsters",1]},
"facet_ranges":{},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Have you reindexed your content after changing the field definition? The already existing tokens won't change unless you index your documents again, preferably by deleting all contents of the index first.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for you advice! After reindexing all data the segmentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the definition of a field (unless you're *only* changing the "query" part of an analysis chain that has separate query and index chains), you'll have to reindex your content.

Since the facet module works on the actual tokens generated in the index, you have to clean out the old index and reindex all your content, so that each value is processed again and divided into tokens matching the behaviour you're looking for.

If all your documents are still present when you're reindexing (so all the old ids are still there), you don't have to clean out the index first, since all the old tokens will be overwritten. But to be sure you can delete everything first, then reindex your content and see the new tokens.

You can also do this while in production as long as a commit doesn't happen in between; first issue the delete, then reindex and then commit. Until the commit happens all the old data will still be available (but be aware that other threads or other code can issue a commit while you're working on the index, so be sure you're the only one issuing commits first).